# How to to bind textbox to MySQL datasource in wpf

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

Okay so the totourials I've been following to make my application have been based on the winforms side of c# where as my app has been based on wpf. However even though my app works fine, I'm told that there's a better way of binding my textboxes using MVVM. I however have been having a difficultt time finding MySQL related totourials that are wpf based that cover MVVM data-binding.

This is my current way of doing things, and so far it works. Apparently it could be better...

```
        string sqlcon = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = root";
        string query = "Select * from users.login where tag = '" + this.tag.Text + "' ;";

        new MySqlConnection(sqlcon);

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        MySqlDataReader rdr;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved");

            while (rdr.Read())
                {

                    //Declarations

                    string susername = GetString(rdr, "username");
                    string spassword = GetString(rdr, "password");

                    string ssecurity = GetString(rdr, "question");
                    string sanswer = GetString(rdr, "answer");

                    //Binding strings to textboxes

                    username.Text = susername;
                    password.Text = spassword;

                    question.Text = ssecurity;
                    answer.Text = sanswer;

                }
                con.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Maybe I'm not looking in the right places but I couldn't find anything specific on MySQL data-binding that had anything to do with xaml. What would be the best way to do this in wpf? Even just an example will do fine. Just so I can get an idea at least.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way would be to use entity framework:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx

MVVM Entity Framework tut

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx
Try to get some knowledge of it first if u actually want to use it.

I first did it the same way u did, but now I use this, I find it way easier.
Also when using MVVM u can just make a project for the entity framework object, and link to your modules.

---

If u want to do it like you do it now, you can do it like this:

some tuts:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124160/Using-WPF-MVVM-for-Database-Access

**VIEW**
add an item source to your object,

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

and try to get stuff from the database loaded in there, that's already a big step.

Comment: Just my two cents about two of those references you cited. That first one "WPF/MVVM Quick Start Tutorial" is not really very good. However, that second one "Using WPF MVVM for Database Access" I found to be very useful! Thanks for mentioning that one - I've been putting it to good use!